# VS Code Spell Checker

Tags: visual-studio-code

I enabled the VS Code extension, "Code Spell Checker," and it works great. However, I wanted to include words from my custom dictionary file so the words in it aren't flagged as incorrect. I tried the following in my settings.json:

```
"cSpell.customUserDictionaries": [
    "name": "Custom",
    "description": "These are words from my custom dictionary.",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\Joe\\Documents\\Custom.txt",
    "addWords": false
],
```

But the words in Custom.txt are still marked as incorrect.

How can I configure Code Spell Checker so that it's able to load all the words in Custom.txt and ignore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [package.json](https://github.com/streetsidesoftware/vscode-spell-checker/blob/master/packages/client/package.json#L520-L549) that configuration is expecting a typeof array of objects, so the following should work:

```
"cSpell.customUserDictionaries": [
    {
        "name": "Custom",
        "description": "My desc",
        "path": "C:\\Users\\Joe\\Documents\\Custom.txt",
        "addWords": false
    }
],
```

And per their description:

> File Format: Each line in the file is considered a dictionary entry

Comment: That was it! I was sending an array instead of an object embedded in the array. Thank you so much.